# Calculate the largest palindromic number from the product of two 6-digit numbers (100000 to 999999)

Tags: java, programming-challenge, interview-questions, palindrome

Are there any efficient ways to solve this problem,
for example using bitwise operator?

```java
    public static boolean isPal(long num) 
    {
        String numStr = Long.toString(num);
        String rNumStr = "";

        boolean result = false;

        for (int i = numStr.length() - 1; i >= 0 ; --i)
            rNumStr += numStr.charAt(i);

        //System.out.println(numStr + "," + rNumStr);
        try 
        {
            if (Long.parseLong(numStr) == Long.parseLong(rNumStr))
                result = true;
            else  
                result = false;
        }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //System.err.println("Unable to format. " + e);
        }
        return result;

    }

    public static void calcPal(int rangeMin, int rangeMax)
    {
        long maxp = 0, maxq = 0, maxP = 0;
        for (int p = rangeMax; p > rangeMin; p--)
            for (int q = rangeMax; q > rangeMin; q--)
            {
                long P = p * q;
                if (isPal(P))
                    if (P > maxP)
                    {
                        maxp = p; maxq = q; maxP = P;
                    }
            }
        System.out.println(maxp + "*" + maxq + "=" + maxP);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        calcPal(10, 99);
        calcPal(100, 999);
        calcPal(9000, 9999);
        calcPal(10000, 99999);
        calcPal(990000, 999999);
    }
```

The largest palindrome which can be made from the product of two 2-digit (10 to 99) numbers is 9009 (91 × 99). Write a function to calculate the largest palindromic number from the product of two 6-digit numbers (100000 to 999999).

Comment: it is my interview question

Answer (score 6):

In an interview setting it is quite hard to come with an efficient solution (unless you happen to be very good in mental multiplication; however a \$99 * 91\$ example is a strong hint). The key to an efficient solution is an observation that

\$999999 * 999001 = 999000000999\$

is a quite large palindromic product. It means that you don't have to test the entire 6-digit ranges of multiplicands. It is enough to test multiplicands only in \$[999001.. 999999]\$ range. Just \$10^6\$ candidate pairs rather than \$10^{12}\$.

BTW, a similar identity holds for products of longer numbers as well.

Next, you may notice that there are just one thousand palindromic numbers larger than \$999000000999\$ (they are in form of `999abccba999`), and to qualify as a solution is must have a 6-digit factor larger than \$999001\$. This implies the following algorithm (in pseudocode):

```
base = 999000000999
abc = 999
while abc >= 0
    cba = reverse_digits(abc)
    number = base + abc * 1000000 + cba * 1000
    for factor in 999001 to sqrt(number)
        if number % factor == 0:
           return number
    abc -= 1
```

The `reverse_digits` of a 3-digit number could be done extremely fast (a lookup table, for example). Still a \$10^6\$ or so rounds, but no expensive tests for palindromicity.

All that said, since the problem stems from [Project Euler #4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) it is possible that it admits a more elegant number-theoretical solution.

Answer (score 4):

### Bug

```
    for (int p = rangeMax; p > rangeMin; p--)
        for (int q = rangeMax; q > rangeMin; q--)
```

You are not including `rangeMin` in either of the loops, so you will never test products which involve the lower limit.  You want `>=` in the loop condition:

```
    for (int p = rangeMax; p >= rangeMin; p--)
        for (int q = rangeMax; q >= rangeMin; q--)
```

### Commutativity

Note that `p * q == q * p`, so you don't need to test all combinations in the range:

```
    for (int p = rangeMax; p > rangeMin; p--)
        for (int q = rangeMax; q > rangeMin; q--)
```

Only the ones where either `p >= q` or `q >= p`, which will reduce your search space by close to 50%!  For example, you could change the `q` range to start at the current `p` value and go down from there:

```
    for (int p = rangeMax; p >= rangeMin; p--)
        for (int q = p; q >= rangeMin; q--)
```

### Test order: Fastest tests first!

`isPal(P)` is an involved function which will take a bit of time.  In comparison, `P > maxP` is blazingly fast.  So instead of:

```
            if (isPal(P))
                if (P > maxP)
                {
                    maxp = p; maxq = q; maxP = P;
                }
```

how about:

```
            if (P > maxP)
                if (isPal(P))
                {
                    maxp = p; maxq = q; maxP = P;
                }
```

### Early termination

If `p*q` is ever less than `maxP`, then multiplying `p` by any smaller value of `q` is a waste of time; you can break out of the inner loop, and try the next value of `p`.

If `p*p` is ever less than `maxP`, and the inner loop only multiplies `p` by `q` values which a not greater than `p`, then you can break out of the outer loop, too!

### String Manipulation

The following is inefficient, because temporary objects are being created and destroyed during each iteration.

```
    for (int i = numStr.length() - 1; i >= 0 ; --i)
        rNumStr += numStr.charAt(i);
```

It is much better to use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build up strings character by character, because the `StringBuilder` maintains a mutable buffer for the interm results.

Even better, it includes the [`.reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) method, which does what you need in one function call.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(numStr);
String rNumStr = sb.reverse().toString();
```

### Unnecessary Operations

Why convert `numStr` to a number using `Long.parseLong(numStr)`?  Isn't the result simply `num`, the value that was passed in to the function?

Why convert `rNumStr` to a number?  If `num` is a palindrome, then aren't `numStr` and `rNumStr` equal?

```
public static boolean isPal(long num) 
{
    String numStr = Long.toString(num);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(numStr);
    String rNumStr = sb.reverse().toString();

    return numStr.equals(rNumStr);
}
```

Comment: Very minor nitpick: "Fastest tests first" is a reasonable heuristic but even from a speed perspective is not the only axis worth considering. "Most selective test first" is also a reasonable heuristic, and the interplay between test speed and selectivity is intricate. I suspect without measurement that you're right in this case  that the quicker test is a good filter, but perhaps it wants fleshing out why.

Comment: In this particular case, as mentioned "you could change the q range to start at the current p value and go down from there." You could do one better than that, and start `q` at `maxP / p` if larger. That could allow the `P > maxP` test to be removed altogether.